# PHP script to clear cache in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php

I created the following script and put it to cron job on server. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
include 'includes/defines.php';
include 'includes/framework.php';

$conf = JFactory::getConfig();

$options = array(
    'defaultgroup' => '',
    'storage'      => $conf->get('cache_handler', ''),
    'caching'      => true,
    'cachebase'    => $conf->get('cache_path', JPATH_SITE . '/cache')
);

$cache = JCache::getInstance('', $options);
$cache->clean('cachegroup');
```

Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some details, eg. messages or symptoms, that help people understand what '...does not work' actually means.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to go for the cache cleaner component in Joomla.

It's a lot better as the plugin has compatibility with latest version and can clean cache at intervals too.